# how to change the rotation direction on keypress in javafx

Tags: java, animation, javafx, rotation

I have two circles that I want to turn them around a pivot clockwise if the right key is pressed and counter clockwise if the left key is pressed but my code does not work.

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.effect.GaussianBlur;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Popup;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import static java.lang.Math.cos;
import static java.lang.Math.sin;

public class Main extends Application {
    public static final double CIRCLES_CENTER_X = 600;
    public static final double CIRCLES_CENTER_Y = 450;
    public static final double CIRCLES_RADIUS = 15;
    public static final double CIRCLES_DISTANCE = 300;
    public static final double GAME_HEIGHT = 700;
    public static final double GAME_WIDTH = 1200; 

    private Stage primaryStage;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(GAME_WIDTH);
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(GAME_HEIGHT);
                    final Scene scene;
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        scene = new Scene(root, Main.GAME_WIDTH, Main.GAME_HEIGHT); 

        Circle orangeCircle = new Circle(Main.CIRCLES_CENTER_X + Main.CIRCLES_DISTANCE / 2 * cos(0),
                Main.CIRCLES_CENTER_Y + Main.CIRCLES_DISTANCE / 2 * sin(0),
                Main.CIRCLES_RADIUS, Color.ORANGE);
        Circle yellowCircle = new Circle(Main.CIRCLES_CENTER_X - Main.CIRCLES_DISTANCE / 2 * cos(0),
                Main.CIRCLES_CENTER_Y - Main.CIRCLES_DISTANCE / 2 * sin(0),
                Main.CIRCLES_RADIUS, Color.YELLOW);

        Pane game = new Pane(orangeCircle, yellowCircle); 
        root.setCenter(game);

        SimpleIntegerProperty angle = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
        root.setOnKeyPressed(ke -> {
            if (ke.getCode().toString().equals("RIGHT")) {
                angle.set(360);
            }
            if (ke.getCode().toString().equals("LEFT")) {
                angle.set(-360);
            }
        });
        root.setOnKeyReleased(ke -> {
            if (ke.getCode().toString().equals("RIGHT")) {
                angle.set(0);
            }
            if (ke.getCode().toString().equals("LEFT")) {
                angle.set(0);
            }
        });

        Rotate orangeCircleRotation = new Rotate(0, Main.CIRCLES_CENTER_X, Main.CIRCLES_CENTER_Y);
        orangeCircle.getTransforms().add(orangeCircleRotation);
        Rotate yellowCircleRotation = new Rotate(0, Main.CIRCLES_CENTER_X, Main.CIRCLES_CENTER_Y);
        yellowCircle.getTransforms().add(yellowCircleRotation);
        Timeline rotationAnimation = new Timeline();
        rotationAnimation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        angle.addListener((ov, old_val, new_val) -> {
                    System.out.println("fk");
                    rotationAnimation.stop();
                    while (rotationAnimation.getKeyFrames().size() > 0) {
                        rotationAnimation.getKeyFrames().remove(0);
                    }
                    rotationAnimation.getKeyFrames().add(
                            new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(2000),
                                    new KeyValue(orangeCircleRotation.angleProperty(), angle.getValue())));
                    rotationAnimation.getKeyFrames().add(
                            new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(2000),
                                    new KeyValue(yellowCircleRotation.angleProperty(), angle.getValue())));
                    rotationAnimation.play();
                }
        );
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
        return primaryStage;
    }
}
```

It works almost fine but when i press a key and release it the circles does not stop. they just start turning backward until the last rotation change point and keep repeating that so also when i press the key again it jumps sometimes.(Because the backward turn has reached its end and starts from the beginning)(Hard to explain!you have to see it for yourself!)
Does anyone know how to fix or achieve this?

Comment: Try switching the rate between +1 and -1, instead of manipulating the key frames.

Comment: i tried it but it didn't work it didn't have that problem anymore but now when i rlease it jumps, note that also when the keys are released i set the rate to 0.

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE]? Otherwise it's just guesswork...

Comment: i can but it's really a hard work bc the code is 600 lines and if i want to extract this part of it it really will take a while!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't try to manipulate the key frames while the animation is in progress. Instead you can just pause/play the animation and change the rate. The only "gotcha" here is that it seems the animation ignores the change in rate if it is paused, so you need to call `play()` *before* `setRate(...)`.

Here's the modified SSCCE:

```
import static java.lang.Math.cos;
import static java.lang.Math.sin;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class RotatingCircles extends Application {
    public static final double CIRCLES_CENTER_X = 600;
    public static final double CIRCLES_CENTER_Y = 450;
    public static final double CIRCLES_RADIUS = 15;
    public static final double CIRCLES_DISTANCE = 300;
    public static final double GAME_HEIGHT = 700;
    public static final double GAME_WIDTH = 1200; 

    private Stage primaryStage;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(GAME_WIDTH);
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(GAME_HEIGHT);
                    final Scene scene;
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        scene = new Scene(root, GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT); 

        Circle orangeCircle = new Circle(CIRCLES_CENTER_X + CIRCLES_DISTANCE / 2 * cos(0),
                CIRCLES_CENTER_Y + CIRCLES_DISTANCE / 2 * sin(0),
                CIRCLES_RADIUS, Color.ORANGE);
        Circle yellowCircle = new Circle(CIRCLES_CENTER_X - CIRCLES_DISTANCE / 2 * cos(0),
                CIRCLES_CENTER_Y - CIRCLES_DISTANCE / 2 * sin(0),
                CIRCLES_RADIUS, Color.YELLOW);

        Pane game = new Pane(orangeCircle, yellowCircle); 
        root.setCenter(game);

        Rotate orangeCircleRotation = new Rotate(0, CIRCLES_CENTER_X, CIRCLES_CENTER_Y);
        orangeCircle.getTransforms().add(orangeCircleRotation);
        Rotate yellowCircleRotation = new Rotate(0, CIRCLES_CENTER_X, CIRCLES_CENTER_Y);
        yellowCircle.getTransforms().add(yellowCircleRotation);
        Timeline rotationAnimation = new Timeline();
        rotationAnimation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        rotationAnimation.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), new KeyValue(orangeCircleRotation.angleProperty(), 360)));
        rotationAnimation.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), new KeyValue(yellowCircleRotation.angleProperty(), 360)));

        root.setOnKeyPressed(ke -> {
           if (ke.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
               rotationAnimation.play();
               rotationAnimation.setRate(1);
           } else if (ke.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) {
               rotationAnimation.play();
               rotationAnimation.setRate(-1);
           }
        });
        root.setOnKeyReleased(ke -> {
            rotationAnimation.pause();
        });


        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        root.requestFocus();
    }


    public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
        return primaryStage;
    }
}
```

BTW In this code you really don't need two separate rotations, since they are identical. Just create a single rotation and add it to both circles' transforms lists. It may be different in your real code, of course...